# Getting component values out of pixel data & iphone

Tags: iphone, image-processing

I'm developing an image editing application for iphone. I've seen many questions similar to mine, but couldn't find a relevent answer. I have generated the pixel data as,

```
NSData* pixelData = (NSData*)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(originalImage.CGImage));
```

Now, i need to get the component values (alpha,R,G,B) from this. How can i do that? Also i need to modify these components and write it to the image. What is the method to implement that??
pls help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics) might have some relevant answers.